# When creating an end to end iOS app, should the front end or back end be created first?

Tags: ios, cocoa, lamp, frontend, backend

I've been a developer for 10 years (non iOS), and working for a large company have never created applications end to end. Just worked on very large applications, on pieces.

I'm starting to get into iOS for fun, and have an app in my head that I want to create. I've wireframed the entire thing using the iOS app 'interface'. Since then, I've begun to start coding. I have about 15 scenes in storyboard (the total app will probably be 100+), and right now I'm just using hardcoded 'fake' data.

However, I've recently begun to think that maybe I should be creating the database and some initial data there instead of using all this hardcoded fake data.

Does anyone have any suggestions and reasons why one way is better than another?

Should I create the back end before the front end? If I do, then each new scene I add I can work the real data in from the beginning instead of having to replace fake hard coded data.

Also, I know little about creating back ends. The application I'm creating is nothing like twitter, but for data access and for this example, let's say it is. It's main view of the application is something like twitter. The user can hit refresh and get many new data points ('tweets' in twitter) from the server. So the application could be very data intensive. Am I best off using something like Parse and paying for their services, or creating something in LAMP, or something else. I've worked with SQL and database a lot in my last 10 years and am very comfortable with that aspect of the back end.

Thoughts? Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd definitely work on the back end first, establish models (which are probably gonna evolve as the app gets bigger). This way you can have solid foundations to build the app on.

Comment: I have no idea what your app does, but you're doing something wrong if it's going to need 100+ StoryBoard scenes. Good iOS apps (and mobile apps in general) are about "do one thing, and do it well".

Comment: Depends on how you look at it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say you have 3 options here :

**Front-end first, back-end afterwards**

Good thing is while developing your front-end, you may understand what's really relevant and what isn't. You probably won't do anything unnecessary on the back-end part. A bad thing though is that bad stuff may happen when you try to connect you back-end to your front-end, and involve some code refactoring on the front-end side, if you don't make sure they at least *can* work together.

**Back-end first, front-end afterwards**

You may here not really see where you're going while developing the back-end. You'll see (you may even know it already) that what you'll create for the client-side may not really be as it looked in your head.. You'll probably have to rework a lot on the back-end.

**Front-and-back-end together**

This is how I usually work. Start the front-end just as you did with hard-coded data, and start asap to work on the back-end. Move your boilerplate data on it, just so you can make sure they communicate well. Then, try to work on both simultaneously. That way, if you change your mind about something on one side, you won't have to redo much code on the other side.

---

Regarding the back-end solution, pretty much all I can say is that I used Parse.com services, and it's really good. In my case, I was not ready to create an entire back-end by myself. If you can, maybe you don't need them. But, (and it's a big one), Parse's SDK can take care of the whole communication between your back-end and your front-end. You don't have to manage network availability, caching stuff, and every thing you have to think about when you develop for a mobile OS. This is very nice.

Their free plan lets you run 1M queries every month, which is quite a lot. But if you want to go further and reduce the number of requests to Parse, you can combine your own back-end and theirs. It may not work for your specific case, but you can have the user access your server to check if new data is available, and only then query Parse. For example, for a news app, have the news on parse.com, store the most recent news date on your server, save the last update date on the client device, and before accessing parse, compare the dates with your server. If needed, query parse, if not, go to the cache (handled by parse's SDK). That way you can limit the number of queries and stay in the free plan.

You should probably try to estimate the number of queries you'll have per month and the monetary impact before choosing.

Just my own opinion :]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to add new features to your app with the smallest possible complexity. Like e. g. "The user can see a list of all registered users." - This example might not fit perfectly well for your case, but I hope you get the point: build one small thing at a time.

But for these small things: make the full trip front and back. Since it shouldn't take you too long to complete such a feature, it doesn't really matter if you complete the frontend or the backend first. So for this part: basically what @rdurand already said ;)

Regarding the backend I see two options:

1. Either you create some REST-Services yourself. The choice of technilogy should depend on what you know already. I am a big fan of [JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services), but if you don't already have some java experience you might have hard time with this.
2. Use some kind of SAAS-API. I've heard some good things about http://www.apiomat.com/, but never used it myself...

Good luck ;)